# following-sibling for list-element

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I would like to create a list item and the format is right as it is. However, I would like to add the string '**or**' to alternatives.
My XPath control is not working properly. If I have a `List` and an underlying `SmallList`, the function is ignored.

If the list is not there, everything works as desired. However, I do not come to the correct expression. I'm using XSLT 1.0. An example follows.

XML:

```
<University>
    <Class>
        <Student>John Doe</Student>
        <List>
            <SmallList>
                <Student>Jane Doe</Student>
            </SmallList>
        </List>
    </Class>
    <AlternativeClass>
        <Class>
            <Student>Richard Roe</Student>
        </Class>
    </AlternativeClass>
</University>
```

What the result should look like:

```
<div>
   <p data-role="heading">University-Heading</p>
   <ul>
      <li>John Doe
         <ul>
            <li>Jane Doe</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parablock bold_">or</li>
      <li>Richard Roe</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

As i mentioned `<li class="parablock bold_>or<li>` is missing.
If I want to remove the `List`-Block, the result looks as expected (e.g. Jane Doe in this example).

```
<div>
   <p data-role="heading">University-Heading</p>
   <ul>
      <li>John Doe</li>
      <li class="parablock bold_">or</li>
      <li>Richard Roe</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The construct for the following-sibling should look like this (following-sibling of BBB should be XXX):

```
<AAA>
    <BBB>
        <CCC/>
    </BBB>
    <XXX>
        <DDD/>
        <EEE/>
    </XXX>
</AAA>
```

My XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="University">
    <div>
        <!-- HEADING FOR UNIVERSITY -->
        <p data-role="heading">
            <xsl:text>University-Heading</xsl:text>
        </p>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<!-- CLASS -->
<xsl:template match="Class">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <!-- 'OR' BEFORE ALTERNATIVE CLASS -->
    <!-- I GUESS THAT THE MISTAKE IS IN HERE -->
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][self::AlternativeClass]">
        <li class="parablock bold_">
            <xsl:text>or</xsl:text>
        </li>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<!-- CLASS-NODE WITH LIST -->
<xsl:template match="Class[List]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Student"/>
</xsl:template>
<!-- ALTERNATIVECLASS -->
<xsl:template match="AlternativeClass">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<!-- STUDENT IN CLASS AND SMALLLIST -->
<xsl:template match="SmallList/Student | Class/Student">
    <li>
        <xsl:if test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = 'Para'">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">parablock</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::List]"/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
<!-- LIST -->
<xsl:template match="List">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
<!-- SMALLLIST -->
<xsl:template match="SmallList">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

.NET XSLT Fiddle: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement for the following sibling is actually correct. The problem is that the `Class` that does have a following `AlternativeClass`, also has a child `List` element, which means it gets matched by this template (Because it has the extra condition on it, the template gets a higher priority)

```
<xsl:template match="Class[List]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Student"/>
</xsl:template>
```

As this does not have the following-sibling check, your expected output does not get created.

You can just add the condition to this statement too

```
<xsl:template match="Class[List]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Student"/>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][self::AlternativeClass]">
        <li class="parablock bold_">
            <xsl:text>or</xsl:text>
        </li>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Although this is a bit of code duplication, so you could put that logic in a named template, or perhaps you can merge the two "Class" templates into one...

```
<xsl:template match="Class">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="List">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Student"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][self::AlternativeClass]">
        <li class="parablock bold_">
            <xsl:text>or</xsl:text>
        </li>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I just forgot about the extra condition - higher priority. 



The code duplication is explained by my entire XSLT, as it is bigger and more complex. However, I wanted to break the description down to a minimal and understandable example. Nevertheless, thank you!